# Linking to other nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, uri

I'm looking to add a field to a content type that lists nodes. Basically, I need that users are able to choose the node they want to link to, and then (in the template) output the link to that node.

This seems like a basic thing to do; I'm using Drupal 7 but can't for the life of me work out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use the "node reference" field in Drupal 7, you need the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 'node reference' field for this.